# Querying Cosmos DB by type property

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

In my project i want to add inheritance for some classes and save the generated objects to a documentcollection in the Cosmos DB database. To save the information about the type i use this preference in JSON.net: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

But how can i query the collection by type without retriving all documents with LINQ in a typesafe way. The best would be to add a property to those classes named for example `Type` which contains the information of the "$type" property of the JSON Object. Then i can query something like this:

```
       return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(DocumentCollectionUri).Where(entity => entity.Type == typeof(Car).ToString());
```

This LINQ Query would be translated to SQL and then sent to the server. I only get back those objects of type car. This would be the optimum, is something like this possible and fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need it your `TEntity` property to implement an interface of some sort, lets way `ICosmosEntity` which has an `EntityType` property which is a string.

Then all your `TEntity` objects will need to implement this interface and they will set the `nameof(TEntity)` as the `EntityType`.

That way you can have your queryable look like this: `return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(DocumentCollectionUri).Where(entity => entity.EntityType == nameof(Car))` which will return exactly what you need.

If you get stuck then I would recommend you check how [collection sharing](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#collection-sharing) works in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). Sounds like exactly something you need.

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of Cosmonaut.*